# Bulk zeroing of elements in a scipy.sparse_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've got a scipy.sparse_matrix A and I want to zero-out a decently-sized fraction of the elements.  (In the matrices I'm working with today, A has about 70M entries and I want to zero-out about 700K of them).  I have those elements available in a couple different formats, but for now they're in a sparse_matrix B of the same dimension as A with 0/1 values.

If these were dense matrices (EDIT: numpy arrays), I could do
A = A-A*B
but I haven't been able to come up with any easy way to do these with sparse matrices.  (or really any way at all beyond (a) iterating through the elements in B and setting A to 0 at those elements or (b) converting everything to dense, which for the sizes I have will just barely fit in memory...)

Comment: So, you want to zero out all the indices `(i,j)` s.t. `B[i,j] == 1`?

Comment: I do, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy's sparse matrices have a `multiply` method that does pointwise multiplication. You can simply do:

```
A = A - A.multiply(B)
```

I thought you may have to run the `eliminate_zeros()` method to get rid of the zeroed entries, but apparently that is not necessary:

```
>>> sp_mat
<1000000x1000000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> zero_mat
<1000000x1000000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 96 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> sp_mat - sp_mat.multiply(zero_mat)
<1000000x1000000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 904 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```